# How to filter on based on user resource field and schemaExtension properties together on Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to filter users having certain schemaExtension and assignedPlan. But i receive an error response.

here is [my request](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users%3F%24filter%3DassignedPlans%2Fany(x%3Ax%2FservicePlanId%20eq%204828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7%20and%20capabilityStatus%20eq%20%27Enabled%27)%20and%20exthpvhyp3h_imported%2FisImported%20eq%20true%26%24count%3Dtrue&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&headers=W3sibmFtZSI6IkNvbnNpc3RlbmN5TGV2ZWwiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImV2ZW50dWFsIn1d), and [schemaExtension i used](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=schemaExtensions%2Fexthpvhyp3h_imported&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com).

Response can be seen below.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal 'guid'4828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7'' at '39' in 'assignedPlans/any(x:x/servicePlanId eq guid'4828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7' and capabilityStatus eq 'Enabled') and e2_7a1a4a282deb46ab9b054b0186f0f945_exthpvhyp3h_imported/isImported eq true'.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-03-15T11:45:39",
        "request-id": "e36d0163-7486-4c0c-aa26-9ef2f815b416",
        "client-request-id": "3cf2d2a3-59d1-4b7a-e5ee-c54a16a82ce3"
    }
}
```

}

How can i filter based on assignedPlans and schemaExtension at the same time?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter assignedPlans using the below query.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=assignedPlans/any(a:a/servicePlanId eq bf6f5520-59e3-4f82-974b-7dbbc4fd27c7 and a/capabilityStatus eq 'Enabled')`

Add header `ConsistencyLevel=eventual`.

But you cannot filter schema extensions as specified in the [Known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#filtering-on-schema-extension-properties-not-supported-on-all-entity-types) document. After getting results from above query, use that data and filter it on your end by writing the code.

Comment: So far i was using the same query you gave. But wanted to see if a query such as this possible. Thanks for your answer.